# Segues initiated directly from view controllers warning in storyboard xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Hi I have created button programmatically and I connected it to another view, but I got segue warning

that I should use `prepareForSegue` method for storyboard but I don't know how, there are some sample on Internet but I get an error when I used that sample, would you please help me

here is my code

**Creating Button**

```
 UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
 button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 201.0/255.0 green: 201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
 button.tag = currentTag;
 currentTag++;
 [button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
 [button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
 [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(80*x, 32*y, 80, 32); 
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [buttonView addSubview: button];
```

**Action for button**

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WeekView" sender:self];    
}
```

**Prepare for segue** **MY Warning**

**Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier for use with -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"WeekView"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"WeekView"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the Segue programatically or in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 31):

**Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier for use with -`[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`**

This warning occurs when you drag a segue directly from a View Controller in Storyboard (aka, not from a button or any action control) and don't type in an Identifier (Name).

You have to give these ones a Identifier or else there's no way to call them programmatically... which is the only reason why you would link a segue like this.

In Xcode 8, you should be able to double click the warning to have the storyboard bring up the offending segue so that you can add a name to it.

Comment: Just so frustrating to take over a project that has a warning like this - is there any way to tell where in IB this segue was made?

Comment: @powerj1984 I had this problem as well when looking back at an older project. I had to click on each storyboard segue and check if it's originating from a view controller. If it is, then I give it an identifier. Another solution would be to get Xcode 5's help to identify the source.

Comment: Pro tip: Double click the warning while in the storyboard and it will jump you to the offender.

Comment: Also you can view the warning in the log file, and there should be segue identifier. Then you just open storyboard as source code and cmd+f for that identifier.

Comment: Thanks @AdamWaite, I updated my answer with your comment.

Comment: I have **Xcode 8.0** and double clicking opens a new window of Storyboard

Comment: You're right, they changed it to a single click. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have Xcode 8.0 and after click on warning it just show storyboard but with Xcode 8.1 (GM) it shows exact segue.

Comment: Actually in Xcode 8.2.1 it just throws me on storyboard rather than to an offending segue.

Comment: Just for people in 2019: Xcode 11.0 throughs almost same error and is easily fixed by clicking on the offending segue and giving it and ID in the attributes tab

Answer (score 13):

This was solved my problem.

Go to Storyboard > Check for all Push or Pop relation segue.

Select each segue relationship > Check Attribute inspector properties  > Storyboard Segue section

In that section give **identifier** for all segue.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 5 I made this warning go away by naming not only the segues but the view controllers they lead to - each view controller needs a Storyboard ID. If you only name the segues this (misleading) warning will still appear.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same warning. You have to check every segue if it has an identifier as XCool said.

> Xcool - I had this problem as well when looking back at an older project. I had to click on each storyboard segue and check if it's originating from a view controller. If it is, then I give it an identifier.

Also check your **unwind segues!** This solved the problem for me.