# What does this Xcode error mean?

Tags: xcode

I got this Xcode error that says ***"segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier"***. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this SO question: [Segues initiated directly from view controllers warning in storyboard xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135741/segues-initiated-directly-from-view-controllers-warning-in-storyboard-xcode)

> "Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an
>   identifier for use with `-[UIViewController
>   performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`
>
> This warning occurs when you drag a segue from the View Controller
>   icon (aka, not a segue from a button or action) and don't give it a
>   segue name.
>
> You have to give these ones a name or else there's no way to call them
>   programmatically... which is the only reason why you would link a
>   segue like this.
>
> You should be able to double click the warning to have the storyboard
>   bring up the offending segue so that you can add a name to it."