# Can't find segues without identifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've got a warning in Xcode 6 and 7 that says:

"Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier"

However, when I look at ALL the segues in the storyboard, they all have identifiers, and I call them all programmatically. It's not a show stopper by any means - the app builds and is totally useable. I just don't like warnings.

There are somewhat related questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135741/segues-initiated-directly-from-view-controllers-warning-in-storyboard-xcode), but it's not the issue I'm seeing.

Are there places that hidden segues can live? Or a master list of segues that I can look at?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> a master list of segues that I can look at

Absolutely. Control click on the storyboard's listing in the Project navigator and choose Open As > Source Code. Now you can read — and search — the storyboard as XML. Look for a `<segue ... />` without an `identifier` attribute.

Comment: Blast! I had an unwind segue that I had forgotten about!

Comment: Oh - and for anyone else looking at a similar problem - my crufty 'unwind' segue didn't show up on the visual part of the storyboard. It was just a single line amongst many in the tree...lord knows when I put that in there or what I was trying to do...

Comment: I think some hidden segues are created automatically.

Comment: @DavidMoles No, a segue in a storyboard is an object like any other. It doesn't come into existence "hidden" or "automatically" any more than a button or a view controller would.

Comment: @matt: Lots of objects are created automatically as the result of adding other objects to a storyboard, or even as the result of creating a new storyboard. Create a new Cocoa app in XCode (I'm using 8 beta), open `Main.Storyboard` as source, and search for `segue`. You'll find something like `<segue destination="XfG-lQ-9wD" kind="relationship" relationship="window.shadowedContentViewController" id="cq2-FE-JQM"/>`. In IB, this is listed as _Relationship "window content" to "View Controller"_, & you can't set an identifier on it. Not exactly hidden, but the segue-ness isn't obvious either.

Comment: @DavidMoles There is nothing "hidden" about a relationship segue. Moreover, in this question, we're talking about triggered segues, _not_ relationships (relationship segues). Finally, look carefully at the question and my answer: the question was how to find segues without identifiers. I told him how to find them. I never said the segues without identifiers he would find would be _only_ the one he was looking for, but I did say the one he was looking for would be found in that way, and I was right.

Comment: @matt Well, I'm talking about the _"Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier"_ error, which I'm still getting, and the only `<segue/>` tag without an `identifier` attribute in my storyboard was the relationship segue. Probably I'm just looking at a beta bug, but maybe consider updating your answer to note that relationship `<segue/>` tags without `identifiers` are normal and to be expected?

Comment: @DavidMoles I'm not going to update anything. This question is about iOS and I stand by it. Instead of crabbing about my answer, it seems like you have the basis of a completely different and very helpful question. Maybe consider asking it as a question? That way you can even provide directions for reproducing the problem and others (including me) can learn something from that.

Comment: @matt I'm sorry you feel I'm attacking your answer.

Comment: Kool: Mine was a relationship segue which I guess is normal when you have a Navigation Controller

Answer (score 5):

Once you've followed the suggestions in this post, you might need to **restart Xcode**. One indication for this is that the warning count is greater than the actual number of warnings that are showing up in the warnings panel. Doing a Clean or Clean Build Folder, rebuild, etc. may not clear this warning. I've experienced this issue with builds as late as Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: yeap, dat did do it :)' I tried numerous tricks and fixes to no avail however w/o restarting xcode. so cannot tell which worked :'(

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I couldn't find a segue without an identifier even when I searched the Storyboard's Source Code (thanks @matt). What I did to remove the warning was:

1. In the top menu go to Product > Clean
2. In the top menu go to Product > Alt + Clean (to clean the build folder)

Comment: yeah that removes them... but when you re-build, they'll show up again...