# why show this warning: Unsupported Configuration: Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier

Tags: swift

when i run my project, the xcode editor show the warning. I don't understand about the warning. I could not find any mistake or error but still showing the warning message.

Comment: Do you assign identifier to your viewController from storyboard?

Comment: I believe you should first go through this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135741/segues-initiated-directly-from-view-controllers-warning-in-storyboard-xcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segues initiated directly from view controllers warning in storyboard xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135741/segues-initiated-directly-from-view-controllers-warning-in-storyboard-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you create the segue by dragging from the viewController, rather than from say a UIButton or other element.  The reason is that in order to execute the segue programmatically you need to specify an identifier like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BOOK_LEAVE_SEGUE" sender:sender];
```

Otherwise there is no way of knowing which segue to perform.

So click on the segue in the storyboard, open attributes pane and give it an identifier.

[image: Where you should set the identifier]